# Как построить линии уровня на карте с помощью python Basemap

Tags: python, карты, matplotlib

Всем привет. У меня есть два массива, в одном - координаты по широте, в другом - по долготе. Сетка регулярная, с шагом 0.75 градуса и по широте, и по долготе. Длины массивов разные, широта - 14, долгота - 17. Также есть массив с маской земля-море, т.е. там нолики и единички для каждой пары координат. Как мне нанести эти данные на карту? Я посмотрела всякие примеры, там для этого используется Basemap, map.contour(lat,lon,mask), но он выдает очень странные линии уровня. Плюс мне нужно сначала произвести конвертацию исходных координат в координаты проекции карты, но функцию lat,lon=map(lat,lon) использовать не получается, потому что агрится компилятор на неравенство длин массивов. Пожалуйста, помогите.

Comment: Добавте в вопрос фрагмент кода, в котором у вас возникли затруднения.